# Reduce .apk file size based on Application Type in android studio

Tags: android

[image: My Code]

My Drawable folder contain 100 images.  When I choose `c_dev` from build variants it uses 50 images from drawable.  Balance 50 image not use this time.  It also same when I choose `b_dev`.  But `.apk` file takes 100 images.  So its size is increased.  How do I reduce `.apk` file size based on Build types?

Comment: Please paste your code into the post rather than providing a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `minifyEnabled true` & `shrinkResources true` in your `build.gradle` file
2. Apply `ProGuard` in your `build.gradle` file
3. Convert your drawable images & PNGs to WebP format by right clicking and selecting `Convert to WebP` your `res` folder

These tips are proven, suggested as a best practice by Android Developer documentation itself and you will surely see a reduced .apk as a result.